# Realtek 8822BU-based Wi-Fi / Bluetooth adapter not connecting to internet

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I got a GAROGYI Wi-Fi/BT module for cheap on Amazon. Initially it worked fine with my PC and my laptop, but after updating my PC's bios from something to 2501, the Wi-Fi portion of it would not work.

Many permutations of the USB Configuration settings in the BIOS->advanced menu yield no improvement, with one or more combinations of settings rendering the adapter useless entirely (adapter shows up in network adapters in device, not working with error 10 in Device Manager, no Bluetooth)

list of facts:

- USB3 USB drive works fine - not a problem with USB3 not enabled
- works on laptop, even the led blinks (like how it did before) - not a problem with adapter
- doesn't work on any USB3 ports - not problem with front I/O
- old Windows drive has same issue - not problem with Windows update
- many uninstalls of the xhci controller - might not be problem with xhci
- 5v voltage at 5.2v - hope that isn't the problem

In `usbtreeview` it shows that it connects with the USB2 High-speed portion of the port only and not the USB3 super-speed part (it recognises that it supports it)

Specs:

- Asus B85M-G
- Intel Core i5 4570
- unpopular brand 450w PSU
- Bubalus something case
- AMD Radeon RX 570
- GAROGYI Wi-Fi AC1300 + BT5.0 USB3 adapter (https://www.amazon.com.au/dp//B09J9X3ST9, unavailable)
- TP-Link 150mbps PCIe 1x card

Edit: the RealTek website doesn't seem to carry drivers for the 8822bu, but GAROGYI supplied drivers with a (sketchy but safe) link on the product page to a Google Drive folder.

Comment: I find 2 from Amazon: https://www.amazon.com/GAROGYI-AC1300Mbps-Wireless-Supports-10-9-10-15/dp/B09VT585QY and https://www.amazon.com/GAROGYI-Adapter-1300Mbps-Wireless-10-9-10-15/dp/B09VS7XT9L. Which one is this? What "error 10" exactly do you see, where and when? Have you tried with [Realtek's driver](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/rtl8812bu-software)? Please don't put new info in comments, but [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1777496/edit) your question instead so everything relevant is readily available.

Comment: I am not sure why the suggestion for a better wireless NIC would be downvoted. I think this what you need to do.

Comment: @Peregrino69 hello pere, thanks for editing my post.

Comment: @Peregrino69 In regards to the links, it is neither of them. The unit I got was listed at the link in the post, and has both wifi ac1300 AND bt5 0. Those modules don't have bt. As for error 10 location, I'll update the post. Those realtek drivers seem to be for the 88ONE2bu, which is a different, seemingly wifi only, chip. The same website doesn't seem to carry the drivers for the 88TWO2bu.

Comment: I have to second @John - junk this and get a brand-name adapter. Just the fact that one can't find the manufacturer... I wonder if that even contains a bona-fide Realtek chip. Neither Realtek nor Google recognize 88ONE2bu or 88TWO2bu. GAROGYI isn't present in AliExpress or Banggood.  USPTO knows it, it's a registered trademark of a Shenzen-based company producing [make-up products](https://uspto.report/TM/90786009)... and RTL8822BU is a USB 2 [Wi-Fi/BT4.1](https://www.realtek.com/en/products/communications-network-ics/item/rtl8822bu) chip "applicable for TV and Set-top box application"...

Comment: I undeleted my answer. Perhaps someone might recognize it as a valid answer

Comment: @Peregrino69 It seems that I didn't clarify about the names i made up. The 88one2bu is the 8812bu, but with the 1 made to a one for emphasis. Ditto for 88two2bu.

Comment: LOL you're right :-D Funny enough, while RTL8822BU is USB2.0, RTL8812BU is USB3.0. One would assume that the more capable chip of the same family would have the same USB interface. Then again the webpage might have an error too.

Comment: It seems that an answer to this question has been deleted and used as an audit test. Why is that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cheap wireless adapters may be of dubious quality and also may not work in all computing devices.

I suggest a better USB wireless adapter and try that.

There are many good USB wireless adapters.  It is very important to check the chipset and use something different than / better than low end Realtek.

Good chipsets in good quality Alpha or Panda USB wireless are usually very good.

I have a Panda USB wireless that is excellent.

Comment: It seems that I might have to go this way. Another person online (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/798088/windows-11-stopped-seing-wi-fi-adapter-realtek-882) seems to have the same problem with their 8822bu based adapter, meaning I have to swallow the hard to swallow pill and pay the extra for a name brand wifi adapter